Django- how to make only the author view their own private posts
For my django app I want to enable the user to select whether a post is public or private.
This is my best attempt so far:
views.py
def home(request):
    recipes = models.Recipe.objects.filter(recipe_private, recipes)
    context = {
        'recipes': recipes
    }
    def recipe_private():
        for recipe in recipes:
            if recipe(is_private=True) and recipe.author == self.request.user:
                True
            else:
                False
    return render(request, "recipes/home.html", context)

And here is my models.py:
class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    serving = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    temperature = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    prep_time = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    cook_time = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    ##tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    is_private = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('recipes-detail', kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

The logic works in my head but not in practice, how would I improve this? I want it so only the author can see their own private posts, anyone who isnt the author shouldnt be able to see a post marked as private.

You filter with:
from django.db.models import Q


def home(request):
    recipes = models.Recipe.objects.filter(
        Q(author=request.user) | Q(is_private=False)
    )
    context = {'recipes': recipes}
    return render(request, 'recipes/home.html', context)


Note: It is normally better to make use of the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL [Django-doc] to refer to the user model, than to use the User model [Django-doc] directly. For more information you can see the referencing the User model section of the documentation.


I am using the auth_user_model, so I should amend to request.auth.user. ?

You can use or operator. something like this.
recipes = models.Recipe.objects.filter(recipe.author == self.request.user) or models.Recipe.objects.filter(is_private=False)


First conditon recipe.author == self.request.user will filter user
own recipe
Second condition is_private=False will filter all those recipe which are declared public


This is plain wrong. Either you meant to do a union of two querysets (then it's |, not or) or to union two conditions (as in another answer), but or will not do what you expect. If the user owns at least one recipe, this will return only owned recipes, not including public recipes created by others.
